IBM EVENTSTREAM Kafka Connector on openshift Debezium oracle connector Encountering Error
I am getting an error in openshift Yaml when creating connector  org.apache.kafka.commonerrors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata.
Kafka - IBM EVENTSTREAM
Deployed - Openshift
What should I be doing instead to fix this problem?
Thanks

This issue could be possibly related to the your current Kafka connector configuration. Please review your configurations like bootstrap URL, SASL configurations, and certificates for connecting to IBM Event Streams.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
